# C# .NET - rewrite a string value in ICollection

Tags: c#, .net, string, collections

How can I change a first value in this collection?

```
ICollection<string> vals = new List<string>();
```

This does not work for the collection:

```
vals[0] = "xxx";
```

Comment: It is because there is no indexer property created on ICollection

Comment: you can get first object in your collection with Linq `vals.First()` but strings are immutable, so you can't change them

Comment: Honestly, while the duplicate does answer your _specific_ question I'd **strongly** consider not using `ICollection`. `ICollection` says **I don't care about indexing or order** - and yet the very nature of your question shows you **do** care about indexing and order. The short answer is - leave it as a `IList` / `List` rather than a `ICollection`.